# Highchart formatter issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to create a highchart. I have 3 arrays. First array contains dates, second array contains float values and last array contains integer values.
I set tooltip setting decimal values doesnt work. Also I want to add pB series to highchart. How can I do?

**First array**

```
dates=["201401", "201401", "201401", "201402", "201402", "201402"];
```

**Second array**

```
krc=["2.22", "3.67", "3.03", "2.22", "3.03", "3.67"];
```

**Last array**

```
pB=["2", "4", "3", "2", "3", "4"];

$('#dvzKr').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text:dates[0]+" / "+ dates[max_y] +" Dates",
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: '',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: dates
    },
    yAxis: {
        min:1,
        title: {
            text: 'Krc Values'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#000000'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Krc Values',
        color: '#F7A35C',
        data: krc
    }]
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle ?

Comment: Why is your data having strings instead of numbers??

Answer (score 1):

You have array on strings rather than number so you have to convert them to numbers

```
//Second array

var krc = ["2.22", "3.67", "3.03", "2.22", "3.03", "3.67"].map(Number);

//Last array

var pB = ["2", "4", "3", "2", "3", "4"].map(Number);
```

You can add pB series to highchart as

```
series: [{
  name: 'Krc Values',
  color: '#F7A35C',
  data: krc
}, {
  name: 'pB Values',
  color: '#A7A35C',
  data: pB
}]
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/wj7je542/)

Comment: do you want secondary yAxis for `pB` series.